# why do I constantly get asked to close "snap-store" after I have done so and re-issued the apt comands required to refresh it?

Tags: snap

This is getting -VERY- anonying. I am getting the following message on a constant basis.
`Pending update of "SNAP-STORE" snap. Close app to avoid disruptions (xx days left).`

I know that you have to kill the running snap-store and then do a sudo snap refresh snap-store  but then several days later the messages start all over.

Comment: Because several days later there is a different new update. Life is like that.

Comment: At least one person is active updating snap-store. quite many packages has no active updates - be glad.

Comment: Then whatever app is being updated is not one that I use. So far the only update "outstanding" has been the same one - for "snap-store". This morning is the first time in a long time that I did not receive the annoying prompt that I have to do something just to "eliminate" the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that you have to kill the running snap-store and then do a sudo snap refresh snap-store but then several days later the messages start all over.

Not sure whether this is correct.

This indeed is an annoying new way of handling pending snap updates. Snaps (and actually for regular apps, that is also not ideal) cannot be updated while the application is open. Let now the browser be a program that is frequently used. Most of the time snap attempts to update the browser, the browser is open.

You could close the browser, but that will not trigger a new update attempt by snap. So most likely, you close the system and next day your browser is open, snap attempts to update, and you have the same message.

The most practical way of getting rid of this message is to close all your applications, then indeed do a manual refresh of snaps: `sudo snap refresh`. This way, you are good until the next update.

It will be good to add your support to filed issues about this: this implementation cause bad user experience.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to where I can comment?   In this particular case, the outstanding update was ````snap-store  41.3-66-gfe1e325  638  48MB  canonical✓  -```` which I was prompted to "fix" for almost a week, even though I received messages like: ````sudo snap refresh snap-store
snap-store 41.3-66-gfe1e325 from Canonical✓ refreshed````   however for the first time in a week, I have not received that message (yet) today.